# Whitelisting a Google Chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I need to block Flash plugin by default and only allow it on manually approved sites, while allowing the PDF plugin to run anywhere automatically. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [FlashBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl) - does exactly what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, my knowledge of permissions in Chrome is a bit... lacking.  This sounds like something that should be done in your firewall... and not at a workstation level.  In most firewall appliances, it's fairly easy to block certain mime-types & such on-the-fly and white-list some sites.  The advantage to this approach is that even if a user switches to IE, Opera, Firefox or whatever else to access whatever annoying flash site... they're still unable to get there.

Comment: I have to disagree, this has nothing to do with firewalls. It's not like I need to keep my network's users at bay: I only want to reduce CPU usage at my own laptop. So while I theoretically can switch browsers and while I technically can compose `iptables` rules to block incoming Flash rules, that would be a crotch rather than a simple and elegant solution. FYI, the opposite of what I need (blacklisting/disabling a plugin) can be easily done in Chrome config.

Comment: I understand now... I thought you were shooting for a network of users... not a 1-off on a roaming laptop.  Using iptables to block http-traffic based on the content of the stream is even worse though.  I agree that this is a very good question.

Comment: And oops! I really meant 'crutch' there. :\ For some reason I can't edit my own comment here although I can do it on StackOverflow.